# Memory leak problem?

Tags: ipad

How i releasing the dataArray from following snippet,

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getData: (NSString *)dbPath
{

    NSMutableArray *_dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT DISTINCT name FROM databaseTable"];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlQuery UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                [_dataArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0)]];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return _dataArray;
}
```

The above method gives me memory leak and it getting me serious problem in future working of application.

Answer (score 3):

```
return [_dataArray autorelease];
```

If you want to returned retained objects you need to make that clear by following the naming conventions. the method should start with new, create or copy. Otherwise you should return a autoreleased object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious leaks in the code you posted.  The function is returning a NSMutableArray that has been allocated, so the caller would be responsible for calling `release` at some later point.  Or, you may choose to make this an `autorelease` object.

Also, you probably want to call sqlite3_close() only if sqlite3_open() succeeded (i.e., move sqlite3_close() to *inside* the first `if` statement).  Same idea for sqlite3_finalize().

There is some one-time initialization that SQLite does implicitly, but you shouldn't need to worry about that.  Check the docs for:

```
int sqlite3_initialize(void);
int sqlite3_shutdown(void);
```

What type of object(s) are being reported as leaks?